# Redux Observable: dispatch action on multiple clicks (two or more)

Tags: javascript, redux, rxjs, redux-observable

I'm using redux observable as a middleware for redux to deal with side effects. I want to dispatch action `A` only when action `B` was emitted more than twice in some specified period of time (say 500ms).

My attempt for this: [demo](https://jsbin.com/magizocene/1/edit?html,css,js,output)

Here is how epic looks:

```
const pingEpic = action$ =>
  action$
    .buffer(action$.ofType(CLICK).throttleTime(500))
    .map(x => x.length)
    .filter(x => x >= 2)
    .mapTo({ type: PING });
```

This epic correctly accumulates clicks in lists and filters those that are longer than 2, but the PING action is dispatched after another additional click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find it easier to nut out complicated rxjs by breaking it down into smaller bits.

So, you want to PING on a double-click and PONG on a single-click, and CLICK is the only source of events.

**double-click** [Ref](https://gist.github.com/mauriciosoares/5f7d185e900a23895e24)

```js
const doubleClick = action$ =>
  action$.ofType(CLICK)
    .buffer(action$.ofType(CLICK).debounceTime(500))
    .map(x => x.length)
    .filter(x => x === 2)
    .mapTo({ type: PING });
```

**single-click**

```js
const singleClick = action$ =>
  action$.ofType(CLICK)
    .buffer(action$.ofType(CLICK).debounceTime(500))
    .map(x => x.length)
    .filter(x => x === 1)
    .mapTo({ type: PONG });
```

**PING/PONG**

```js
const pingEpic = action$ =>
  Rx.Observable.merge(
    singleClick(action$), 
    doubleClick(action$)
  )
```

**Note**, it seems to work with straight replace of `throttleTime` with `debounceTime`,

```js
const pingEpic = action$ =>
  action$
    .buffer(action$.ofType(CLICK).debounceTime(500))
    .map(x => x.length)
    .filter(x => x >= 2)
    .mapTo({ type: PING });
```

but you don't get any PONGs happening with this. (Adding a console.log to the reducer shows the flow a bit better)

```js
const pingReducer = (state = { isPinging: 'NO' }, action) => {
  console.log('reducer', action.type)
  ...
```

Here's the example [Fiddle](https://jsbin.com/kicequjazu/1/edit?html,js,console,output)

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what I wanted to achieve :)